# Loop through children in xml with php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Probably easy but it just cannot get it working. I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<Competition>
  <gameSchedule>
    <game>
      <ID>58256</ID>
      <Nr>1N-001</Nr>
    </game>
    <game>
      <ID>58278</ID>
      <Nr>1N-001</Nr>
    </game>
    <game>
      <ID>58986</ID>
      <Nr>1N-001</Nr>
    </game>
  </gameSchedule>
</Competition>
```

I want to loop through the game nodes, so I can get all the ID's. But even trying to get the first node doesn't return anything. I thought

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($kalender) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$firstElementChild = $xml->children()[0];
echo($firstElementChild);
```

where $kalender = the xml. I thought that would show me the XML starting from gameSchedule, but it returns an empty string. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have a look at [the examples in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

`$xml->children()` returns a [Traversable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.simplexmlelement.php), not an array.

You can try this approach:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($kalender) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->{'gameSchedule'}->{'game'} as $game) {
  print "ID = {$game->{'ID'}} Nr = {$game->{'Nr'}}\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with xml, I would argue that the best way to handle it is xpath:

```
$ids = $xml->xpath('//game/ID');
foreach($ids as $id)
   echo $id . '<br>';
```

Output:

```
58256
58278
58986
```